# How to register `tsconfig-paths` for `tsc-watch`?

Tags: nestjs, tsc, tsconfig-paths

I am trying to set up relative paths for my application running it with `tsc-watch`. But when I try to access enum in *shared* folder from *feature* folder, I get "Error: Cannot find module". Running the application with `ts-node` works fine. How I can use `tsconfig-paths` with `tsc-watch`?

Here is repo of my project: https://github.com/Nako68l/nestjs-task-management

Answer (score 0):

I'm the creator of `tsc-watch` I've just checked out your project, and it looks like it works... Have you managed to find a solution?

Comment: Yes, I've added [module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias) package to create aliases. But this is hacky solution cause it requires having a copy of paths in `packaje.json`, and add `require` for this module in `main.ts`. 
Also, it does not change aliases to relative links in the compiled project.
I will try to use [link-module-alias](https://github.com/Rush/link-module-alias) but it also has some critical issues like [deleting source files with '@' paths prefix](https://github.com/Rush/link-module-alias/issues/3)

Comment: I guess my problem is related to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26722) and [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10866) issue of `tsc`, that it is not able to convert non-relative paths from `tsconfig.json` to relative ones on project compilation

Comment: How is it working?

Comment: It's listening to the output from tsc process and "understands" if there was an error of success

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** You have `IS_TS_NODE` env var during running `tsc-watch`.

> How I can use `tsconfig-paths` with `tsc-watch`?

`tsc-watch` have not knowledge or responsibility about path mapping. The mapping can be implemented with such packages:

1. [module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias) for Node.js run time. It modifies the default `require` behavior.
2. [@ef-carbon/tspm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ef-carbon/tspm) for changing js files after typescript compiling.
3. [tsconfig-paths](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths) for Node.js/TS-node run time. It also modifies the default `require` behavior. tsconfig.json is used for the configuration. For Node.js run time, you should include a copy of the tsconfig.json in compiled folder.

At your repository you have mix of 1 and 3 solutions:

- `module-alias` is used, if env var `IS_TS_NODE` is undefined ([src/main.ts](https://github.com/Nako68l/nestjs-task-management/blob/master/src/main.ts#L3))
- `tsconfig-paths` is used with ts-node, because you have `-r tsconfig-paths/register`

You have `IS_TS_NODE` env var during running `tsc-watch`, so `module-alias` doesn't work.

**Use one solution to avoid such situation.**

Comment: I've tried `tspm` but it does not work. You can see my implementation on the [no-module-aliases branch](https://github.com/Nako68l/nestjs-task-management/tree/no-module-aliases). Also, `tsmp` repo has [open issue](https://github.com/ef-carbon/tspm/issues/48) about  integration with NestJS

Comment: `IS_TS_NODE` is set only for `ts-node` in `start` script. For `tsc-watch` in `start:dev` it is not set. But I've got the solution with `module-alias` to work for development.
But when I try to run my build in `dist` folder outside of my project with `node dist/main.js` I get `Error: Cannot find module 'module-alias/register'`

So currently I am in the search of a solution that will give me the ability to have aliases resolved to relative urls on build with `tsc`.